# MySQL database performance select on ultra large table

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have a sales data table in which average 1,329,415 rows are inserted in daily. I have to generate report from the table daily in different formats. But the query from the table is too much slow. Here is my SHOW CREATE TABLE command output.

```
CREATE TABLE `query_manager_table` (
  `mtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `region_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `rtslug` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `dpid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `route_number` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rtlid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `retailer_code` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform_code` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `skid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `group` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `family` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `volume` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` float(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `outlets` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `visited` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `channel` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subchannel` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tpg` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ioq` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dpid`,`route_id`,`rtlid`,`prid`,`skid`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (YEAR(date) * 100 + QUARTER(date))
(PARTITION y2017q1 VALUES IN (201701) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2017q2 VALUES IN (201702) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2017q3 VALUES IN (201703) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2017q4 VALUES IN (201704) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2018q1 VALUES IN (201801) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2018q2 VALUES IN (201802) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2018q3 VALUES IN (201803) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2018q4 VALUES IN (201804) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2019q1 VALUES IN (201901) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2019q2 VALUES IN (201902) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2019q3 VALUES IN (201903) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2019q4 VALUES IN (201904) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Now I just want to know the by retailer sales from 1st September to 9th September by following query -

```
SELECT
            query_manager_table.dpid,
            query_manager_table.route_id,
            query_manager_table.rtlid,
            query_manager_table.prid,
            SUM(query_manager_table.`volume`) AS sales,
            1 AS memos
        FROM
            query_manager_table
        WHERE
            query_manager_table.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01'
        AND '2018-09-08'    
GROUP BY
            query_manager_table.dpid,
            query_manager_table.rtlid,
            query_manager_table.date
```

But it takes about 500-700 sec . I have added `dpid IN (1,2,.....)` AND `prid IN (1,2,....)` as both fileds are added as primary key. Then output comes after 300sec. What I am doing wrong?

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | query_manager_table | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 129065467 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

When I add all dpid and prid in where condition then EXPAIN look like

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | query_manager_table | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 128002 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    +----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to optimize table or query?
If I run EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT... for the first one then get -

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions                                                                                      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | query_manager_table | y2017q1,y2017q2,y2017q3,y2017q4,y2018q1,y2018q2,y2018q3,y2018q4,y2019q1,y2019q2,y2019q3,y2019q4 | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 127129410 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

For the 2nd one I get -

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions                                                                                      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | query_manager_table | y2017q1,y2017q2,y2017q3,y2017q4,y2018q1,y2018q2,y2018q3,y2018q4,y2019q1,y2019q2,y2019q3,y2019q4 | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 153424 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think you have confused yourself with Primary key and index. You should rather index `dpid`, `rtlid`, `date` (a composite index of these three), instead of adding them to primary key

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Isn't primary key itself a index?

Comment: Yes it is. But that does not mean you define every field as a PK. Primary key basically refers to a main referencing unique field in your database.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, My PK is right according to my project scenario. Maximum time I actually search with date range. dpid is used rarely. Should I add date and dpid as key separately?

Comment: When you say that your "PK is right according to your project scenario" what do you mean exactly? I agree with @MadhurBhaiya; your key structure appears to have more fields than are strictly required to uniquely identify each record. What is this "project scenario" that you say states otherwise, please?

Comment: @BobRodes, I have over 3M insert operation on that table and sometimes user also modify data. During overload somehow for server failure duplicate data are found. So I made them key for both preventing duplicate and also indexing. What do you suggest? Making them unique key and add other key separately? My table size is more than 100GB.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEXes` are used for efficiency in `SELECTs`.

The one `PRIMARY KEY` (in MySQL) is, by definition a unique `INDEX`.  It should have a minimal set of columns that uniquely identify a row.

Any unique index (including the PK) is also a "uniqueness constraint" -- this prevents inserting multiple rows with the same set if values.

Indexes are used "from the left".  That is, with `INDEX(a,b)`, if `a` is not useful, it won't get to the `b`.

`PARTITION BY LIST` is virtually useless.  It rarely, if ever, improves performance.  You have shown us a couple of queries; let's see more of the typical queries so we can help you with indexes and partitioning.

```
    WHERE
        query_manager_table.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01'
                                     AND '2018-09-08'
```

begs for `INDEX(date)`.  In a composite index, the columns after a 'range' won't be reached.  That is, in `INDEX(date, x, y)`, testing `date` for a range (such as the 8 days in the `WHERE`), won't let it make use of `x` or `y`.  On the other hand, `WHERE date = '2018-09-01' AND x=1` *will* make use of more of the index.

`float(7,2)` -- don't use the `(m,n)` option on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  Instead, switch to `DECIMAL`.

`INT` is always 4 bytes.  See `TINYINT` (1 byte), `SMALLINT` (2 bytes), etc.  This, alone, may cut the table size in half.

To explain this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`dpid`,`route_id`, ...
WHERE ... AND dpid IN (...) AND ...
```

manages to use the first (remember: 'leftmost') for the pseudo-range `IN`, but can't use anything else in the PK since `route_id` is next.

This explains why the second `EXPLAIN` has a smaller "Rows".  Also, note the "4" in "key_len" -- that's the number of bytes in `dpid`.

After you have made some of those changes, come back so we can discuss using Summary Tables to speed things up.  However, "modify" may lead to complexity in this optimization.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Don't use GUIDs unless you must; they slow actions on large tables down due to the randomness.

Comment: Many thanks for your really explained answer. My server RAM is 64GB and innodb_buffer_pool_size is 21474836480. Most of the time I need data between date range. So what do you suggest? Would I use auto-increment PK and make the existing PK as UK? Also make single index of each column (current PK)? My table size is more than 100GB and increasing everyday.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Please provide `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...` for both queries.

Comment: Question edited. Please have a look. My MySQL version: 5.6.40

Comment: @MdRiadHossain - Notice how all the partitions are listed, thereby indicating that there was no "partition pruning", thereby supporting my contention that `PARTITION BY LIST` is not beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I would not combine actual data fields to make a primary key. I would have a single field, and use an auto-incrementing integer or perhaps a GUID for the value. Having to go through six fields to identify a unique record takes more time than going through one, and as you say you run the risk of duplicate fields if a user is entering key data.

If you have business reasons to make those six fields unique when taken together, you should also work up a routine to identify whether or not an inserted record duplicates an existing one with respect to these fields. If you are batch inserting, you'll want to do this after inserting the records rather than checking each one as you insert it. You'll also want to index these six fields, to speed up your query for duplicates.

As for your `SELECT` query, you'll probably want to index the fields in your `WHERE` clause. In any case, you'll want to read up on execution plans and experiment with different indexes and key structures (probably easier to do on a subset of your data). Google "mysql execution plan" for lots of information.